# Is there a repository of code colour schemes for IdeaJ

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

..like there is for VS at http://studiostyl.es/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [third-party plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=6892) and repository site: http://ideacolorschemes.com/.

Comment: It seems like ideacolorschemes is gone now. :(